# UWP Databinding Error

Tags: xaml

In a UWP, I use the "CollectionViewSource" in  a xaml file, and when I want to bind the source for it, it doesn't work and the error information is

> Input string was not in correct format

What can I do for solving this problem ?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You have to parse the json file into a collection from the corresponding type, then bind to that collection.
Hope it helps you out.